# Execute a php script while joomla plugin is being installed

Tags: php, joomla

I was reading about executing scripts while a plugin is being installed in Joomla, I think (maybe I´m wrong) that you need to configurate an xml file called manifest.xml.

I need to execute a php script while my plugin is being installed, I was reading this:

https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files

But I am not sure about how to do it with tags. I just want to execute a php script while my plugin is being installed.

Comment: Ok, I know but I was read the original documentation and it doesn´t say anything about this. I´m not sure if I can do it or if I cannot do it. I need to resolve this problem and I´m not sure what can I do or what I can´t. I just get information about execute sql scripts and I think that maybe I can execute a PHP script. I was looking for this and I did not found anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a execution a php script yoy should define a file.xml,for example in joomla in folder plugins>search>k2:we have 2 file:
**k2.xml  and
k2.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="search" method="upgrade">
    <name>Search - K2</name>
    <author>JoomlaWorks</author>
    <creationDate>December 8th, 2014</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2006 - 2014 JoomlaWorks Ltd. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <authorEmail>please-use-the-contact-form@joomlaworks.net</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.joomlaworks.net</authorUrl>
    <version>2.6.9</version>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <description>K2_THIS_PLUGIN_EXTENDS_THE_DEFAULT_JOOMLA_SEARCH_FUNCTIONALITY_TO_K2_CONTENT</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="k2">k2.php</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="search_limit" type="text" size="5" default="50" label="K2_SEARCH_LIMIT" description="K2_THE_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_TO_RETURN_WHEN_PERFORMING_A_SEARCH"/>
                <field name="search_tags" type="radio" default="0" label="K2_ENABLE_SEARCHING_IN_TAGS" description="K2_SELECT_IF_YOU_WANT_TO_SEARCH_ITEMS_TAGS_NOTE_THAT_THIS_CAN_BE_VERY_SLOW_ON_LARGE_SITES">
                    <option value="0">K2_NO</option>
                    <option value="1">K2_YES</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

in the section tag  you define k2.php 
in installing plugin,the files copy to folder plugins joomla nd default is disabled.after you active it you can execute it as a script.
in installing file.php can not  executed.
goodluck
goodluck